# HTML5 video poster image not scaling fullscreen on iPad retina

Tags: ipad, html5-video, mobile-safari

I have a fullscreen video on a website. on iPads I want to load the poster image so it is fullscreen as well. The markup and css I have works on a low-res iPad Mini, but doesn't display full-screen on an iPad Retina.

html...

```
    <video autoplay poster="/images/styles/vid_home_screenshot.jpg" id="bgvid" loop>
        <source src="/video/Globe_vid_main_1280x720_v4.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="/video/Globe_vid_main_1280x720_v4.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="/video/Globe_vid_main_1280x720_v4.ogv" type="video/ogg" />     
    </video>
```

This is the css on the video element...

```
video {position: absolute;
       min-width: 100%;
       min-height: 100%;
       width: auto;
       height: auto;
       z-index: -100;
       transition: 1s opacity;
       top: 0;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%,0);
       -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0);
       }
```

[image: iPad Mini screenshot (looks correct)]

[image: iPad Retina screenshot (looks incorrect, same site)]

Comment: It appears to show correctly on iOS8, the iPad I'm testing on that it isn't working correctly is iOS7.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width:auto;
height:auto;
z-index: -100;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover; 
-moz-background-size:cover; 
-o-background-size:cover; 
background-size:cover;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,0);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0);
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this would help solve the issue?